# trying to extend the result type.. unsuccesfully, in F#

Tags: f#

Right now, when I have a Result type, it seems like I need to do a match to find if it is ok, or not.

So, I am trying to simplify this to be able to use if, like that:

```
let a : Result<string, string> = ...
if a.IsOk then ....
```

Here is my attempt

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module ResultHelper =
    type Result with
        member this.IsOk =
            match this with
            | Ok _    -> true
            | Error _ -> false
```

but this will not compile.

Using:

```
    type Result<_, _> with
```

doesn't help either

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Note that `Result.map` does more or less exactly what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @Guran I had no idea result.map was a thing, but it looks like it's exactly what I need since I need to chain operations. thanks!

Comment: you’re welcome. Map and Bind are really nice constructs. Just beware the M-word...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is to give the type parameters names. As a bonus, this will allow you to refer to them in the code if you need to.

```
type Result<'a, 'b> with
    member this.IsOk =
        match this with
        | Ok _    -> true
        | Error _ -> false
```

---

P.S. For the future, please note that "will not compile" is not a good description of a problem. Please make sure to always include the full error message.