# F# saying value not defined in Computation Expression

Tags: f#, monads, computation-expression

I've been working on a State Monad with F# Computation Expression and I'm trying to also utilize Custom Operations. I'm getting some weird behavior that does not make sense. The compiler is reporting that a value does not exist when it was declared just two lines above.

```ml
type State<'a, 's> = ('s -> 'a * 's)

module State =
    // Explicit
    // let result x : State<'a, 's> = fun s -> x, s
    // Less explicit but works better with other, existing functions:
    let result x s = 
        x, s

    let bind (f:'a -> State<'b, 's>) (m:State<'a, 's>) : State<'b, 's> =
        // return a function that takes the state
        fun s ->
            // Get the value and next state from the m parameter
            let a, s' = m s
            // Get the next state computation by passing a to the f parameter
            let m' = f a
            // Apply the next state to the next computation
            m' s'

    /// Evaluates the computation, returning the result value.
    let eval (m:State<'a, 's>) (s:'s) = 
        m s 
        |> fst

    /// Executes the computation, returning the final state.
    let exec (m:State<'a, 's>) (s:'s) = 
        m s
        |> snd

    /// Returns the state as the value.
    let getState (s:'s) = 
        s, s

    /// Ignores the state passed in favor of the provided state value.
    let setState (s:'s) = 
        fun _ -> 
            (), s


type StateBuilder() =
    member __.Return(value) : State<'a, 's> = 
        State.result value
    member __.Bind(m:State<'a, 's>, f:'a -> State<'b, 's>) : State<'b, 's> = 
        State.bind f m
    member __.ReturnFrom(m:State<'a, 's>) = 
        m
    member __.Zero() =
        State.result ()
    member __.Delay(f) = 
        State.bind f (State.result ())


let rng = System.Random(123)
type StepId = StepId of int
type Food =
    | Chicken
    | Rice
type Step =
  | GetFood of StepId * Food
  | Eat of StepId * Food
  | Sleep of StepId * duration:int
type PlanAcc = PlanAcc of lastStepId:StepId * steps:Step list

let state = StateBuilder()

let getFood =
    state {
        printfn "GetFood"
        let randomFood = 
            if rng.NextDouble() > 0.5 then Food.Chicken
            else Food.Rice
        let! (PlanAcc (StepId lastStepId, steps)) = State.getState
        let nextStepId = StepId (lastStepId + 1)
        let newStep = GetFood (nextStepId, randomFood)
        let newAcc = PlanAcc (nextStepId, newStep::steps)
        do! State.setState newAcc
        return randomFood
    }

let sleepProgram duration = 
    state {
        printfn "Sleep: %A" duration
        let! (PlanAcc (StepId lastStepId, steps)) = State.getState
        let nextStepId = StepId (lastStepId + 1)
        let newStep = Sleep (nextStepId, duration)
        let newAcc = PlanAcc (nextStepId, newStep::steps)
        do! State.setState newAcc
    }

let eatProgram food =
    state {
        printfn "Eat: %A" food
        let! (PlanAcc (StepId lastStepId, steps)) = State.getState
        let nextStepId = StepId (lastStepId + 1)
        let newStep = Eat (nextStepId, food)
        let newAcc = PlanAcc (nextStepId, newStep::steps)
        do! State.setState newAcc
    }

type StateBuilder with

    [<CustomOperation("sleep", MaintainsVariableSpaceUsingBind=true)>]
    member this.Sleep (state:State<_,PlanAcc>, duration) =
        printfn $"Sleep"
        State.bind (fun _ -> sleepProgram duration) state

    [<CustomOperation("eat", MaintainsVariableSpaceUsingBind=true)>]
    member this.Eat (state:State<_,PlanAcc>, food) =
        printfn $"Eat"
        State.bind (fun _ -> eatProgram food) state


let simplePlan =
    state {
        let! food = getFood
        sleep 2
        eat food // <-- This is where the error is. 
                 // The value or constructor 'food' does not exist
    }

let initalAcc = PlanAcc(StepId 0, [])

let x = State.exec simplePlan initalAcc
x
```

Here's a picture of the error:
[image]

Comment: I reproduced what you're seeing, but I don't know what's causing it and there's very little documentation on how custom operations are supposed to work. I'll keep trying, but they seem to be a very dark magic indeed! :)

Comment: This is totally a guess, but I think both `Sleep` and `Eat` must have a second parameter that's marked with `[<ProjectionParameter>]` that's ["a function from the currently bound values to the expression that follows the custom operator"](http://blog.mavnn.co.uk/expanding-existing-computational-expressions/).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This all has to do with the deep nature of computation expressions, which, judging by the tags you put on your post, you must already understand are *monads*.

What are monads? It's just a name for this pattern of chaining computations together, passing the result of one as parameter to the next, that's all. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64994978/180286) for a somewhat more comprehensive explanation with examples. Here I'll just assume you know how `bind` and `return` work, especially seeing how you've implemented them for `State` yourself.

And what are computation expressions? They're what you might more generally call "monad comprehensions", which basically means they're *syntactic sugar* for monads. In practical terms, this means that they're clever syntax, which ultimately gets *desugared* to a series of `bind` and `return` calls.

Let's consider a simplified example without `sleep`:

```
state {
  let! food = getFood
  printfn $"{food}"
}
```

This code would desugar into this:

```
state.Bind(
  getFood,
  (fun food ->
    printfn "${food}"
    state.Return ()
  )
)
```

See what happened here? The part of the computation that comes after `getFood` got turned into a function, and this function takes `food` as a parameter. That's how the `printfn` line gets the value of `food` to print - by virtue of it being passed as a parameter to the function.

Custom operations, however, work a bit differently. When the compiler encounters a custom operation, it takes the whole expression (the sequence of `Bind` calls) that came before the custom operation, and passes that whole thing to the custom operation as a parameter.

To see what happens, let's try to `eat`:

```
state {
  let! food = getFood
  printfn $"{food}"
  eat food
}
```

This would get desugared to:

```
state.Eat(
  state.Bind(
    getFood,
    (fun food ->
      printfn $"{food}"
      state.Return food
    )
  ),
  food
)
```

Hmm... See what happened here? The second parameter of `Eat` is `food`, but that's not defined anywhere! It's only valid inside that nested function! This is where you're getting your error.

So to deal with this, computation expressions have a special thing: `ProjectionParameterAttribute`. Here the word "projection" roughly means "transformation", and the idea is that such parameter would be a *function*, which can be called on the result of the computation that's been computed "so far" to extract some part of it.

In practice this means that if we annotate `Eat` like so:

```
member this.Eat (state:State<_,PlanAcc>, [<ProjectionParameter>] food) =
```

Then the desugaring of the above example becomes this:

```
state.Eat(
  state.Bind(
    getFood,
    (fun food ->
      printfn $"{food}"
      state.Return(food)
    )
  ),
  (fun x -> x)
)
```

Notice how the nested function calls `state.Return`, so that the result of the whole `Eat`'s first parameter is the value of `food`. This is done on purpose, to make intermediate variables available to the next part of the computation. This is what it means to "maintain variable space".

And then notice how the second parameter of `Eat` became `fun x -> x` - meaning it's extracting the value of `food` from the intermediate state that has been returned from the `Eat`'s first parameter via that `state.Return`.

Now `Eat` can actually call that function to get at the value of `food`.

```
member this.Eat (state:State<_,PlanAcc>, [<ProjectionParameter>] food) =
    printfn $"Eat"
    State.bind (fun x -> eatProgram (food x)) state
```

Note the parameter `x` - that comes from `state`, funneled into the lambda expression by `State.bind`. If you look at the type of `Eat`, you'll see that it became this:

```
Eat : State<'a, StateAcc> * ('a -> Food) -> State<unit, StateAcc>
```

Meaning that it takes a state computation producing some `'a`, plus a function from `'a` to `Food`, and it returns a state computation producing nothing (i.e. `unit`).

So far so good. This will fix the "*`food` is not defined*" problem.

---

But not so fast! Now you have a new problem. Try introducing `sleep` back in:

```
state {
  let! food = getFood
  printfn $"{food}"
  sleep 2
  eat food
}
```

And now you get a new error: *`food` was expected to have type `Food`, but here has type `unit`.*

WTF is going on here?!

Well, you're just throwing away the `food` inside `Sleep`, that's all.

```
    member this.Sleep (state:State<_,PlanAcc>, duration) =
        printfn $"Sleep"
        State.bind (fun _ -> sleepProgram duration) state
                        ^
                        |
                    This was `food`. It's gone now.
```

You see, `Sleep` takes a computation producing *something* and proceeds to throw away that *something* and run `sleepProgram`, which is a computation producing `unit`, so that's what the result of `sleep` becomes.

Let's look at the desugared code:

```
state.Eat(
  state.Sleep(
    state.Bind(
      getFood,
      (fun food ->
        printfn $"{food}"
        state.Return food
      )
    ),
    2
  ),
  (fun x -> x)
)
```

See how `Sleep`'s result is the first parameter of `Eat`? That means `Sleep` needs to return a computation producing `food`, so that `Eat`'s second parameter can have access to it. But `Sleep` doesn't. It returns the result of `sleepProgram`, which is a computation producing `unit`. So `food` is gone now.

What `Sleep` really needs to do is to first run `sleepProgram`, then to the end of it chain another computation that would return the result of the original `Sleep`'s first parameter. Like this:

```
member this.Sleep (state:State<_,PlanAcc>, duration) =
  printfn $"Sleep"
  State.bind 
    (fun x -> 
      State.bind 
        (fun () -> State.result x) 
        (sleepProgram duration)
    ) 
    state
```

But this is ugly as hell, isn't it? Luckily, we have a handy compiler feature to turn this mess of `bind` calls into a nice and clean program: computation expressions!

```
member this.Sleep (st:State<_,PlanAcc>, duration) =
  printfn $"Sleep"
  state {
    let! x = st
    do! sleepProgram duration
    return x 
  }
```

---

**If you take away one thing from all of this, let it be the following:**

"Variables" that are defined within a computation expression are not really "variables" at all, they only look like them, but in reality they're function parameters, and you have to treat them as such. This means that every operation has to make sure to thread through whatever parameters it got from upstream. Otherwise those "variables" won't be available downstream.

Comment: This answer is outrageously awesome. Thank you! This should be a blogpost in of itself.

Comment: Glad I could help. I do sometimes adopt SO answers to blog posts (check out [our blog](https://medium.com/collegevine-product)), but it's not as simple as copy&paste. A blog post comes at you "out of the blue", so it needs to explain the problem before offering the solution. And here on SO you already did the problem part for me.

Comment: Do you have the full code somewhere I can look at? I'm trying to copy/paste into what I have and I'm getting errors popping up. It's reporting an error at the `sleep 2` line saying the CE it now needs `Yield`. I didn't see you make any changes to the CE in the answer so I'm wondering if I'm missing something else.

Comment: Here, I made a Gist for you: https://gist.github.com/fsoikin/ed822e66fc12bcfcf83b3fdcdcfd1882

Comment: Note that I have described two problems: (1) `Eat` needs `ProjectionParameter`, and (2) `Sleep` needs to tunnel the result though. But both those methods actually have _both_ problems. I wanted to leave that as an exercise, because that way retention is way better.

Comment: The piece that I was missing was I accidentally changed `[<MaintainsVariableSpaceUsingBind=true>]` to `[<MaintainsVariableSpace=true>]` between posting my question and receiving your answer. Thanks! This is incredibly helpful!

Comment: You will be happy to know that I was able to successfully update the `Sleep` method to also use `[<ProjectionParameter>]` and use values declared earlier in the CE.

Comment: Okay, what's weird is that if I chain several `CustomOperation`, the final result appears to call them multiple times. It's like it's nesting the call multiple times.

Comment: Works fine for me. You must have made some other mistake somewhere. You'll have to post another question to figure that out.

Comment: For anyone following, the follow up question is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66713393/f-nesting-of-computation-expressions-and-bind