# F# too many calls to nested Computation Expression

Tags: f#, monads, computation-expression

This questions is an evolution of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66702741/f-saying-value-not-defined-in-computation-expression). I am trying to find out why when I run `State.exec` on the CE that I appear to be getting undesired nesting behavior of the CEs. It seems to be calling them many times. Here is what I have:

```ml
type State<'a, 's> = ('s -> 'a * 's)

module State =
    // Explicit
    // let result x : State<'a, 's> = fun s -> x, s
    // Less explicit but works better with other, existing functions:
    let result x s = 
        x, s

    let bind (f:'a -> State<'b, 's>) (m:State<'a, 's>) : State<'b, 's> =
        // return a function that takes the state
        fun s ->
            // Get the value and next state from the m parameter
            let a, s' = m s
            // Get the next state computation by passing a to the f parameter
            let m' = f a
            // Apply the next state to the next computation
            m' s'

    /// Evaluates the computation, returning the result value.
    let eval (m:State<'a, 's>) (s:'s) = 
        m s 
        |> fst

    /// Executes the computation, returning the final state.
    let exec (m:State<'a, 's>) (s:'s) = 
        m s
        |> snd

    /// Returns the state as the value.
    let getState (s:'s) = 
        s, s

    /// Ignores the state passed in favor of the provided state value.
    let setState (s:'s) = 
        fun _ -> 
            (), s


type StateBuilder() =
    member __.Return(value) : State<'a, 's> = 
        State.result value
    member __.Bind(m:State<'a, 's>, f:'a -> State<'b, 's>) : State<'b, 's> = 
        State.bind f m
    member __.ReturnFrom(m:State<'a, 's>) = 
        m
    member __.Zero() =
        State.result ()
    member __.Delay(f) = 
        State.bind f (State.result ())


let rng = System.Random(123)
type StepId = StepId of int
type Food =
    | Chicken
    | Rice
type Step =
  | GetFood of StepId * Food
  | Eat of StepId * Food
  | Sleep of StepId * duration:int
type PlanAcc = PlanAcc of lastStepId:StepId * steps:Step list

let state = StateBuilder()

let getFood =
    state {
        printfn "GetFood"
        let randomFood = 
            if rng.NextDouble() > 0.5 then Food.Chicken
            else Food.Rice
        let! (PlanAcc (StepId lastStepId, steps)) = State.getState
        let nextStepId = StepId (lastStepId + 1)
        let newStep = GetFood (nextStepId, randomFood)
        let newAcc = PlanAcc (nextStepId, newStep::steps)
        do! State.setState newAcc
        return randomFood
    }

type StateBuilder with

    [<CustomOperation("sleep", MaintainsVariableSpaceUsingBind=true)>]
    member this.Sleep (st:State<_,PlanAcc>, [<ProjectionParameter>] (duration: 'a -> int)) =
        printfn $"Sleep"
        let program d =
            state {
                let! x = st
                printfn "Sleep: %A" duration
                let! (PlanAcc (StepId lastStepId, steps)) = State.getState
                let nextStepId = StepId (lastStepId + 1)
                let newStep = Sleep (nextStepId, d)
                let newAcc = PlanAcc (nextStepId, newStep::steps)
                do! State.setState newAcc
                return x 
            }

        State.bind (fun x -> program (duration x)) st


    [<CustomOperation("eat", MaintainsVariableSpaceUsingBind=true)>]
    member this.Eat (st:State<_,PlanAcc>, [<ProjectionParameter>] (food: 'a -> Food)) =
        printfn $"Eat"
        let program e =
            state {
                let! x = st
                printfn "Eat: %A" food
                let! (PlanAcc (StepId lastStepId, steps)) = State.getState
                let nextStepId = StepId (lastStepId + 1)
                let newStep = Eat (nextStepId, e)
                let newAcc = PlanAcc (nextStepId, newStep::steps)
                do! State.setState newAcc
                return x
            }
        State.bind (fun x -> program (food x)) st


let simplePlan =
    state {
        let! f1 = getFood
        sleep 1
        eat f1
        sleep 2
        eat f1
        sleep 3
    }

let initalAcc = PlanAcc(StepId 0, [])

let x = State.exec simplePlan initalAcc
```

Here is what I expect to get for `x`:

```
> x;;
val it : PlanAcc =
PlanAcc
(StepId 6,
  [Sleep (StepId 6, 3); GetFood (StepId 5, Chicken);
      Sleep (StepId 4, Chicken); EatFood (StepId 3, Chicken);
      Sleep (StepId 2, 1); GetFood (StepId 1, Chicken)])
```

Here is what I get:

```
> x;;
val it : PlanAcc =
  PlanAcc
    (StepId 63,
     [Sleep (StepId 63, 3); Eat (StepId 62, Rice); Sleep (StepId 61, 2);
      Eat (StepId 60, Rice); Sleep (StepId 59, 1);
      GetFood (StepId 58, Chicken); GetFood (StepId 57, Chicken);
      Sleep (StepId 56, 1); GetFood (StepId 55, Rice);
      GetFood (StepId 54, Chicken); Eat (StepId 53, Chicken);
      Sleep (StepId 52, 1); GetFood (StepId 51, Chicken);
      GetFood (StepId 50, Chicken); Sleep (StepId 49, 1);
      GetFood (StepId 48, Chicken); GetFood (StepId 47, Chicken);
      Sleep (StepId 46, 2); Eat (StepId 45, Rice); Sleep (StepId 44, 1);
      GetFood (StepId 43, Rice); GetFood (StepId 42, Chicken);
      Sleep (StepId 41, 1); GetFood (StepId 40, Rice);
      GetFood (StepId 39, Rice); Eat (StepId 38, Rice); Sleep (StepId 37, 1);
      GetFood (StepId 36, Chicken); GetFood (StepId 35, Rice);
      Sleep (StepId 34, 1); GetFood (StepId 33, Rice);
      GetFood (StepId 32, Chicken); Eat (StepId 31, Rice);
      Sleep (StepId 30, 2); Eat (StepId 29, Rice); Sleep (StepId 28, 1);
      GetFood (StepId 27, Chicken); GetFood (StepId 26, Rice);
      Sleep (StepId 25, 1); GetFood (StepId 24, Rice);
      GetFood (StepId 23, Rice); Eat (StepId 22, Chicken);
      Sleep (StepId 21, 1); GetFood (StepId 20, Rice);
      GetFood (StepId 19, Chicken); Sleep (StepId 18, 1);
      GetFood (StepId 17, Chicken); GetFood (StepId 16, Rice);
      Sleep (StepId 15, 2); Eat (StepId 14, Rice); Sleep (StepId 13, 1);
      GetFood (StepId 12, Rice); GetFood (StepId 11, Rice);
      Sleep (StepId 10, 1); GetFood (StepId 9, Rice);
      GetFood (StepId 8, Chicken); Eat (StepId 7, Chicken);
      Sleep (StepId 6, 1); GetFood (StepId 5, Chicken);
      GetFood (StepId 4, Chicken); Sleep (StepId 3, 1);
      GetFood (StepId 2, Chicken); GetFood (StepId 1, Chicken)])
```

I'm fairly certain it has to do with how the `State` is being bound in the `program` CEs since I don't have a problem if I just call `let! f = getFood` a bunch of times.

I tried removing the `let! x = st` and `return x` calls in the `program` CEs thinking that was what was causing the issue, but the compiler complained in the `simplePlan` CE saying, "The expression was expected to have type 'Food' but here has type 'unit'".

Image of error:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're right: it does have to do with binding the incoming computation at `let! x = st`.

But you're also right that you can't just remove that binding, because you need to tunnel through its return value, as I described in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66710942/180286).

But this `let! x = st` is not a problem by itself.

The problem is that you're binding `st` **twice**:

```
    [<CustomOperation("eat", MaintainsVariableSpaceUsingBind=true)>]
    member this.Eat (st:State<_,PlanAcc>, [<ProjectionParameter>] (food: 'a -> Food)) =
        printfn $"Eat"
        let program e =
            state {
                let! x = st  <-- here's the first time
                printfn "Eat: %A" food
                let! (PlanAcc (StepId lastStepId, steps)) = State.getState
                let nextStepId = StepId (lastStepId + 1)
                let newStep = Eat (nextStepId, e)
                let newAcc = PlanAcc (nextStepId, newStep::steps)
                do! State.setState newAcc
                return x
            }
        State.bind (fun x -> program (food x)) st
                                               ^^
                                               here's the second time
```

It's absolutely no wonder the resulting values double: you're doing double the computation at every step!

You need to remove *one* of them, but it's not the one in `let! x = st`, because you do need that `x` so that you can `return x` at the end.

```
    [<CustomOperation("eat", MaintainsVariableSpaceUsingBind=true)>]
    member this.Eat (st:State<_,PlanAcc>, [<ProjectionParameter>] (food: 'a -> Food)) =
        printfn $"Eat"
        state {
            let! x = st
            let f = food x
            printfn "Eat: %A" f
            let! (PlanAcc (StepId lastStepId, steps)) = State.getState
            let nextStepId = StepId (lastStepId + 1)
            let newStep = Eat (nextStepId, f)
            let newAcc = PlanAcc (nextStepId, newStep::steps)
            do! State.setState newAcc
            return x
        }
```

Comment: Holy smokes. It's so much simpler than I thought. THANK YOU!. The answers to these two questions have done more for my understanding of CEs than so many other things that I have read. Thank you!

Comment: Once again, glad I could help.